# React native deep linking issue?

Tags: react-native, expo, deep-linking

When  I click on verify email, I am expecting to get my deep linking "URL" but I am getting  custom "URL" scheme.When I repeat the same process I get the required result.

```js
// result 
//  com.rithmm.mobile://expo-development-client/?    url=http%3A%2F%2F192.168.1.3%3A8081

// expected 
//  https://mydom.com/EmailVerified?token=1234
 const linking: LinkingOptions<RootStackParamList> = {
  prefixes: [
  // https, including subdomains like www.
  `https://${url}/`,
  `https://*.${url}/`,
  // http, including subdomains like www.
  `http://${url}/`,
  `http://*.${url}/`,
   Linking.createURL('/')
],
```

Answer (score 0):

Try in your tab navigator setting a property lazy = false
that solved it out for me